# How to add additional items to menu options of app icon in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell-extension

I have noticed that some of the application like Thunderbird mail in the image below have added their custom option like "compose a new message". I wanted to do the same thing for my application. How is it being done?

[image]